# Highcharts delay building of tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart with a few series.  Each series has millions of points (some graphs will contain 30mill datapoints).  I am already using the boost module.  The chart renders but then there is a significant delay before tooltips will show up.  This delay is sometimes up to a minute and I am sure it is when they are building the tooltips.  Any ideas to speed this up?

What I am thinking is that I would like to NOT have it build the tooltip until the user actually hovers the mouse over the chart.  Is this possible?

Comment: Also with one series, using Boost I see timeKDTree is taking over 30 seconds.  That is the slowdown

Comment: Could you send an online example of your chart with sample data? Try to change some default tooltip settings and check if it helps. Perhaps you've set something wrong, check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/7ropegvt/1/